# How to draw a circle by following MVC architecture

Tags: iphone, model-view-controller, uiview

I am new to iOS platform and i heard about MVC archtecture.
To draw a circle i just create a separate UIView class and override the drawRect: and able to do this.

But now i want to rebuild the same project using MVC architecture.The main aim is to separate my Model part from View & Controller part.So that i can extend my project.

So how can i do this?

Any sample application for reference?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense to me. Drawing a circle, is just the view part. There is no model or controller involved in drawing a circle. You'll need something more complicated for MVC.

Comment: Actually i want to change its shape ,size,color. Then can perform various operation on the circle such as rotate,scale,Pan...Finally save all data in a persistant store...such as NSCoding/NSKeyedArchiver.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to separate. Drawing a circle would generally fit into the "View" part of the MVC architecture, which is what you have already done. Code that would, for instance, change the colour of the circle would live in the "Controller" part, which on iOS is a UIViewController. If you had something storing information on what the circle looked like (i.e. size, colour, etc.), that could be considered part of the model, and can be stored in its own class, pulled in by the view controller and passed to the view when it is neede.

Here is a link that may help.

http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=1969

As for the model side of things, Core Data is a technology that can help.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075

Answer (score 0):

The separation would be the drawing code in drawRect and the size and location in a model with a controller getting the circle attributes from the model and requesting the drawing and passing the attributes to the view.  The model might be another class or an API supplied class such as an NSDictionary.

By creating a separate model if there were multiple circles the controller could make multiple draw requests, one per model circle.  Or there could be multiple views that the circle(s) would be drawn in or different representations such as a text list of the circles attributed in one view and graphic circles in another.

Many patterns seem trivial and not particularly useful in the trivial case yet in a real-world program work very well.